# Left Join One Column in Table 1 to Two Columns in Table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is a "phone number" table and the other is a "calls" table. The calls table has two columns of interest: the originating number column (c.orig) and the terminating number column (c.term).

I'm trying to write a MySQL query that will return all records in the call table where **NEITHER** the c.orig number or the c.term number exist in the numbers table (the "n.num" column in the numbers table).

Here is my SQL query:

```
    SELECT
        c.id, c.date, c.orig, c.term, c.duration
    FROM calls as c
    LEFT JOIN numbers as n ON (n.num = c.orig AND n.num = c.term)
    WHERE
        c.period = '2012-08' AND
        n.num IS NULL
    GROUP BY c.call_id
    ORDER BY c.call_id
    LIMIT 0,300
```

Any ideas?

---

Here is some further clarification:

```
------------------------------
table: numbers
nid     num
1       111-222-3333
2       222-333-4444
3       333-444-5555
------------------------------

------------------------------
table: calls
id      orig            term
1       333-444-5555    999-999-9999
2       999-999-9999    111-222-3333
3       222-333-4444    999-999-9999
4       888-888-8888    999-999-9999
5       777-777-7777    999-999-9999
------------------------------
```

Call IDs 1, 2, and 3 have at least one of the two numbers (orig or term) that can be found in the numbers table.

Call IDs 4 and 5 are situations where neither of the two phone numbers are not in the numbers table. Those are the records that I'm trying to find. Records where neither phone number is found in the numbers table.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You should `Join` table `twice` for this,</strike>

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.date, c.orig, c.term, c.duration
FROM calls as c
        LEFT JOIN numbers as n 
            ON (n.num = c.orig)
        LEFT JOIN numbers m
            ON m.num = c.term
WHERE
    c.period = 'date here' AND
    m.num IS NULL
-- GROUP BY c.call_id
ORDER BY c.call_id
LIMIT 0,300
```

question, i removed your group clause cause i don't see any aggregated function. What else do you want to do?

**UPDATE 1**

based on your examples above, try this edited one.

> Call IDs 4 and 5 are situations where **neither of the two phone numbers
>   are not in the numbers table**. Those are the records that I'm trying to
>   find. Records where neither phone number is found in the numbers

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    calls a
        LEFT JOIN numbers b
            ON a.orig = b.num
        LEFT JOIN numbers c
            ON a.term = c.num
WHERE   b.num IS NULL AND
        c.num IS NULL
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ef3f/4)

Hpe this makes sense.

Comment: Just curious, why did you use "m" instead of "n" in your second join?

Comment: `m` and `n` are called alias. There can be no two tables that can have same alias that is why I did that.

Comment: For some reason this query is returning false ... like it is broken or something. When I try to count the rows it does not return zero like I would expect.

Comment: for better view on you problem, can you post the schema of your tables with samle records on it, also for you desired result. :D if it's ok..thanks.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the second look. I have edited the original question. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Still not working. If I take out the second join then it works. Do you know if MySQL can do a double left join like this?

Comment: @JoeHoskinson weird though. can you look at the [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ef3f/4) i have provided? as you can see, only the two records that `orig` and `term` from `calls` table does not exists on the `numbers` table are shown.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that, logically, the condition in your `ON` clause is applied to every *single* row, not to the lot of them, so you can't really have any single `n.num` be equal to *both* `c.orig` and `c.term`, unless, of course, the two are the same number (which in your particular case would make no sense).

So, what you actually need to be checking there is whether `n.num` is equal to *either* `c.orig` or `c.term`. That is, just replace `AND` with `OR` and you are done:

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.date, c.orig, c.term, c.duration
FROM calls as c
LEFT JOIN numbers as n ON (n.num = c.orig OR n.num = c.term)
WHERE
    c.period = '2012-08' AND
    n.num IS NULL
GROUP BY c.call_id
ORDER BY c.call_id
LIMIT 0,300
```

Answer (score 0):

The question already uses the word EXIST. Well, this is axactly why EXISTS exists:

```
SELECT c.id, c.date, c.orig, c.term, c.duration
FROM calls c
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
   FROM numbers a
   WHERE a.num = c.orig
   )
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
   FROM numbers b
   WHERE b.num = c.term
   );
```

The two subqueries could even be combined into one:

```
SELECT c.id, c.date, c.orig, c.term, c.duration
FROM calls c
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
   FROM numbers ab
   WHERE ab.num = c.orig
   OR ab.num = c.term
   );
```

NOTE: I omitted the period-condition and the LIMIT, which are both irrelevant to the actual problem.

BTW: "date" is a reserved word in SQL. Better not use it as a column name.